# Convert Float to String in C then read it in Python

Tags: python, c, string, floating-point, type-conversion

I am converting a float variable to string in C and sending it to Python using named pipes in Linux. The problem is that I read gibberish characters along with the real value in the Python side.

**C code to convert float into string**

```
char str[64];

sprintf(str, "%f\n", angle);
write(fd_fifo, str, sizeof(str));
```

**Python Code to read the received value and print on the terminal**

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import errno
import time

FIFO = '/tmp/bldc_fifo'

try:
    os.mkfifo(FIFO)
except OSError as oe: 
    if oe.errno != errno.EEXIST:
        raise

print("Opening FIFO...")
with open(FIFO, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as fifo:
    print("FIFO opened")
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        data = fifo.read()
        print(data)
```

**In the terminal prints I see something like this:**

4\W`U7z3\ENU11.415311

**Where my expectation is to see:**

11.415311

Comment: `write(... strlen())`

Comment: or `int len = sprintf(str, "%f", angle);` (no newline too).

Comment: @WeatherVane: I assumed newline was needed in Python ... and also I like them :)

Comment: @pmg oh, your call. The length from `sprintf` is useful generally.

Comment: Yeah, that usefulness trumps everything. +1 to you :)

Comment: @pgm the method you proposed worked, thanks!

Comment: Ok, great @odd. I have a little more time to write an answer now. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strlen()` instead of `sizeof`

```
char foo[99] = "the quick fox";
sizeof foo; /* 99 */
strlen(foo); /* 13 */
```

In your code, the error is in the call to `write()`

```
//write(fd_fifo, str, sizeof(str));
write(fd_fifo, str, strlen(str));
```